# How to refer to controls using variable in a loop?

Tags: vb.net, loops, random, controls

I have labels named: `label1`, `label2`, ...`label16`. I want to assign a random number to all of them.

Something like this could work but I don't know the syntax:

```
for i = 1 to 16
        label(i).text = Math.Ceiling(Rnd() * 99)
next
```

Your suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried to run that code? If so, did it do what you expected?

Answer (score 2):

You can use this using [`Controls.Find`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.find):

```
For i As Integer = 1 To 16
    Dim arrCtrl() As Control = Me.Controls.Find("label" & i, True)

    If arrCtrl.Length = 1 AndAlso TypeOf arrCtrl(0) Is Label Then
        DirectCast(arrCtrl(0), Label).Text = Math.Ceiling(Rnd() * 99)
    End If
Next
```

Answer (score 1):

> **Getting a random Integer**

---

Use the [Random](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random?view=netframework-4.8) class instead of the [Rnd](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/rnd-function) function to get a random `Integer` within a specified range in the `Random.Next(Int32, Int32)` method. Declare a class variable of `Random` type:

```vb
Private ReadOnly rand As New Random
```

> **Finding a range of controls**

---

This code snippet iterates over the `Controls` collection of the container, returns - if any - the `Label` controls where their names are equals to a range of names starts from `label1` to `label16`, and finally, assign a random `Integer` to their `Text` properties:

```vb
Private Sub TheCaller()
    For Each lbl In Controls.OfType(Of Label).
        Where(Function(x) Enumerable.Range(1, 16).
        Any(Function(y) x.Name.ToLower.Equals($"label{y}")))
        lbl.Text = rand.Next(1, 100).ToString
    Next
End Sub
```

Just in case, if the `Label` controls are hosted by different containers, then you need a recursive function to get them:

```vb
Private Function GetAllControls(Of T)(container As Control) As IEnumerable(Of T)
    Dim controls = container.Controls.Cast(Of Control)

    Return controls.SelectMany(Function(x) GetAllControls(Of T)(x)).
        Concat(controls.OfType(Of T))
End Function
```

And call it as follows:

```vb
Private Sub TheCaller()
    For Each lbl In GetAllControls(Of Label)(Me).
        Where(Function(x) Enumerable.Range(1, 16).
        Any(Function(y) x.Name.ToLower.Equals($"label{y}")))
        lbl.Text = rand.Next(1, 100).ToString
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim labels As New List(Of Label) From {Label1, Label2, Label3, Label4}
    For Each l As Label In labels
        l.Text = rand.Next(99).ToString
    Next
End Sub
```

To use your approach

1. Declare a variable for the Random class outside your method (a Form level variable).
2. Create a List of labels.
3. Loop through all the labels in your list and set the .Text property with the .Next method of the Random class.